# Cannot edit Javascript files stored in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio

I have a sharepoint online developer tenant. I created a document Library called Javascripts. I open the Library in explotrer view to edit the files.

When I edit a file with Visual Studio 2015, I cannot save it. I get an error saying the file is checked out or loked for editing by another user. The library  does not even have checkout enabled!)

I can open and edit the files using VS CODE with no problems.

I ran a fiddler trace while trying to save the file from within Visual studio. I see VS sends a Lock Request, and sharepoint responds with an HTTP 423 response:
[image]

I am on my home computer, not domain joined. I am running windows 10.
How can I edit my files using visual studio 2015?

Answer (score 0):

It is a filesystem issue, **unselect the file in Explorer View**, that's what blocking any 3rd party application from editting it.
Explorer has locked the file for its own Explorer purposes.

Best is set a Drive mapping to you SharePoint folder and use that in VS and close Windows Explorer.

http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Map_Document_Libraries_as_Network_Shares

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing the same issue. I tried both avoiding Explorer View and attempting with a mapped drive as Danny '365CSI' Engelman suggested, neither had any impact upon the problem.

One solution I have found is that the problem does not present itself if you edit the files from Visual Studio 2012 instead of Visual Studio 2015.

I wish I had a way to get this working in VS2015 though.